Filter WooCommerce available payment gateways based on user metadata
I'm encountering a problem with a custom function in WooCommerce that filters payment gateways based on user meta. The function is intended to show specific gateways according to the assigned_payment_gateways stored in user meta. However, I'm facing an issue where only Stripe is displayed for regular users, while admin-type users can see all active gateways including default ones like Cash on Delivery (COD) and Direct Bank Transfer from $available_gateways variable.
Here is the function I am using:
function filter_payment_gateways_based_on_user($available_gateways) {
    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) {
        return $available_gateways;
    }

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $user_gateways = get_user_meta($user_id, 'assigned_payment_gateways', true);

    if (!empty($user_gateways)) {
        if (is_string($user_gateways)) {
            $user_gateways = explode(',', $user_gateways); // Convert string to array
        }

        foreach ($available_gateways as $gateway_id => $gateway) {
            if (!in_array($gateway_id, $user_gateways)) {
                unset($available_gateways[$gateway_id]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $available_gateways = [];
    }

    return $available_gateways;
}

I have confirmed that:
The function is hooked with appropriate priority:
`add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_payment_gateways_based_on_user', 20);`

All payment gateways, including COD and Direct Bank Transfer, are active in WooCommerce settings.
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Instead of using custom user metadata for that, you can define first in the function:

an array of the payment IDs that are only available to admins
an array of the customer user roles (I also added "subscriber" user role, as it's used for customers with WooCommerce subscriptions plugin).

Then, If the user is a customer, we hide the payment IDs that are only available to admins.
Try the following:
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_payment_gateways_based_on_user', 20);
function filter_payment_gateways_based_on_user( $available_gateways ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return $available_gateways;

    global $current_user;

    $admin_payment_ids = array('cod', 'bacs', 'cheque'); // Payment IDs Only allowed to admins
    $customer_roles    = array('customer', 'subscriber'); // Customer user roles

    // Target only customer user roles or guests
    if ( array_intersect($current_user->roles, $customer_roles) || !$current_user->ID ) {
        // Loop through available payment gateways
        foreach ($available_gateways as $payment_id => $label_name ) {
            // Hide payment gateways that are only for admins
            if ( in_array($payment_id, $admin_payment_ids) ) {
                unset($available_gateways[$payment_id]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $available_gateways;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.
